# Two equations and two unknowns in matlab for different numbers

Tags: matlab, equation

How to solve two equations and two unknowns code written for different numbers?

For example:

```
aX + bY = c * d
x + y = c
c = 3
d = 30
```

for `a` and `b` for different

```
a = [0:1:30]
b = [60:1:90]
```

for `a=1` `b=60`,`a=1` `b=61`,..... `a=30` `b=90`.

The numbers `a` and `b` are constants, and `X` and `Y` are unknown.

Comment: Did you already read the documentation of matlab? For example [this one](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/solve.html)?

Comment: you have not 2 equations and two unknown here, you have one equation 31x2 + 31x2 = 1x1 and another equation 1x1 + 1x1 = 1x1. Do you want to solve 31 equations for one a and b each time?

Comment: Looop over `a` and `b`, and for each pair of values solve with \

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
%// all a and b you're interested in
As = [(0:30)' (60:90)'];

%// the solution vector is always the same
b  = [90; 3];

%// solve all systems using mldivide
for ii = size(As,1):-1:1
    XY(ii,:) = [As(ii,:); [1 1]]\b; end
```

But, if you'd've been smarter, you'd've recognized that

```
  x = c - y
⇒ a(c-y) = c·d - by
⇒ y = c·(a-d)/(a-b)
```

and therefore, you'd've coded

```
a = 0:30;    c = 3;
b = 60:90;   d = 30;

y = c*(a-d)./(a-b);
x = c - y;
```